# ORDER BY mysql comma separated values

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hi i am trying to order my database by comma separated value but it doesn't seem to be working correctly for me. here is my mysql query.

```
   SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_terms.name = 'Dimmers'
AND meta_key = 'feature_number_of_channels'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY meta_value  ASC
```

And here is a screenshot.
[image]
As you can see from the screenshot they dont seem to be working correctly any help please on how to order these ASC correctly???

Correct order i am looking for is so the highest out of them all then ASC like this

24,48 - 4,6,12,24 - 12 - 6 - 6 - 3

Comment: What's the expected correct order??

Comment: It's not clear what the "correct" order is. Can you provide a sample of the correct ordering for the data in the screen shot?

Comment: You are ordering by `object_id ASC` in the code that you posted. Do you want to change that to `meta_value`?

Comment: sorry had to update quick wrong image the correct order i am looking for is from the highest number so 24,48 - 4,6,12,24 - 12 - 6 - 6 - 3 thanks

Comment: yes sorry changed it to meta_value

Comment: @DCHP For me, it's still not clear.

Comment: So you are trying to order by the highest number within the comma values?  Also, you say you want to order ASC, but your sample output shows it ordering DESC...  (48, 24, 12, 6, 6, 3)

Comment: I think he is trying to order by the highest value in the comma-delimited string meta_value in descending order, effectively MAX(meta_value) DESC, however because MySQL treats that field as a string (presumably it's VARCHAR) it orders by 1-9 based on leading character(s).  @DHCP I'm afraid you'll find what you are trying to do is tricky, though it's not clear where meta_value is coming from.  Are you able to provide some information as to table design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `ORDER BY` to look at the integer value of the string :

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_value, ',', -1), SIGNED) DESC
```

Here's an example:

```
SELECT "24,38" AS meta_value UNION
SELECT 1 AS meta_value UNION
SELECT 30 AS meta_value
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_value, ',', -1), SIGNED) DESC
```

returns:

```
Rows = 3
meta_value
24,38
30
3
```

Good luck!

Comment: It seems that your comma separated values are sorted with highest at the end -- you can extract that value, and convert it to an integer using the method above.

Comment: This works as long as the highest value is always the last value. However it will fail if the highest number is somwehere in the middle. If that also happens in your data then you will have to write a stored procedure that returns the highest number based on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Using order table.field ASC might help you as there are too many tables joined. That way the server would take the exact order from one single table.